Wind's effect on motor-propeller thrust
Hello UAV enthusiasts and experts,
I am working on creating a drone that can carry about 2-3 kgs of payload, let's say the total weight to be around 4 kgs. I require a decent amount of speed and maneuverability, and I set the target at about 15 m/s.
For this drone, I selected a 480Kv motor with 13 inch tri-propellers. This combination provides me with max Thrust to Weight ratio of about 4. So I was confident on this combination, until I read about the wind's effect on thrust generated by propellers.
According to calculations, the max wind speed induced by this motor-propeller, when the air around it is static, is 6 m/s. I read that if the free stream velocity of wind (the relative velocity of wind wrt drone) is such that propeller receives a wind of speed > 6m/s from above, the thrust generated by it goes to zero. As the wind speed below propeller can not be > 6m/s => implying that propellers does not create a force on air, and thus air does not create a thrust on propeller. The problem with this is that it creates a physical limit of speed that my drone can run up to. And that limit is too low for me.
I understand that this is a layman explanation, but overall aerodynamics can go very chaotic. So, I want to know if this statement is true: "If induced wind speed = 6m/s at static air, that the drone can not fly such that relative wind velocity vector's component in motor axis > 6m/s, because it reduces thrust to zero".
If this is true, how do helicopter's and fixed wing drones create thrust at high speeds.
And if false, what is the exact effect of wind speed on the thrust generated by propeller.
Thank you
